# "RECORDING" WAS INVALID. A "RECORDING MODE" OF "V" WAS ASSUMED FOR FILE

Tags: cobol, mainframe

Hi I have written a COBOL program where I am using a file, but while defining file definition it is giving me error, please tell me what to do.

```
       FILE-CONTROL.                
                                    
           SELECT CONTROL0-FILE     
                  ASSIGN TO CONTR.  
                                    
           SELECT APCO-FILE         
                  ASSIGN TO APCOOUT.
                                    
       FD  APCO-FILE.                                                  
I   A "RECORDING MODE" OF "V" WAS ASSUMED FOR FILE "APCO-FILE".   //ERR MSG        
           RECORDING MODE IS V                                         
S   "RECORDING" WAS INVALID.  SCANNING WAS RESUMED AT THE NEXT AREA "A" //ERR MSG
       ITEM, LEVEL-NUMBER, OR THE START OF THE                         //ERR MSG
           RECORD CONTAINS 30 TO 300                                   
           BLOCK CONTAINS 6152 CHARACTERS                              
           LABEL RECORDS STANDARD.                                     
                                                                       
       01  APCOIN-REC-1             PIC X(30).                         
       01  APCOIN-REC               PIC X(300).
```

Comment: I'm not a cobol expert, but this looks like the file is invalid, not a record file or not with the expected column sizes.

Comment: But I have checked , everything mentioned is correct regarding file attributes.

Comment: remove the period after `APCO-FILE.` and everything is fine

Comment: Why the Rexx tag. This is a COBOL problem not a Rex problem. Also you do not mention Rexx anywhere in your problem statement. Please remove the tag.

Comment: @SimonSobisch Thanks it is working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `.` after *APCO-FILE*, it ends the file definition

```
       FD  APCO-FILE.                                                  
           RECORDING MODE IS V                                         
           RECORD CONTAINS 30 TO 300                                   
           BLOCK CONTAINS 6152 CHARACTERS                              
           LABEL RECORDS STANDARD.
```

Change to

```
       FD  APCO-FILE                                                  
           RECORDING MODE IS V                                         
           RECORD CONTAINS 30 TO 300                                   
           BLOCK CONTAINS 6152 CHARACTERS                              
           LABEL RECORDS STANDARD.
```

Comment: Thanks @BruceMartin It is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've been given the solution. I would like to ad some comment which may help you find errors yourself in the future.

The compiler reads what it thinks is a statement, and then verifies syntax, and if an error is found, writes error message(s). It then goes on with the next statment.

So firstly, the fact that there is an error message after `FD  APCO-FILE.`  indicates that the compiler considers the statement to be complete right at this point. Secondly, the fact that there is another error message after `RECORDING MODE IS V`  tells you that the compiler thinks this is another statement, and it doesn't understand it, hence `"RECORDING" was invalid ..`.

So the compiler thinks the part starting with `RECORDING` is a new statement, while you meant it to be a continuation of the `FD` statement. Think about what would cause the compiler and you to disagree, and you might soon see the "." after `APCO-FILE` which should not be there.